# How can I use Google+ to optimize my new website SEO?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, google-plus

Nowadays, we know [SMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media_optimization) by using Google+ (and Facebook, Twitter...) is good for SEO and ranking in SERP.

Then, I would like to use Google+ to optimize my new website SEO but I don't know how can I begin to use it.

I already associate my website with my Google+ profile to get [my face in SERP of Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986) and it works fine.

But now?
I suppose I should make a community grow around my website.
Should I begin a blog with relevant texts, images etc. for visitors and link all my blog posts with my Google+ profile?

How can I use Google+ to optimize my new website SEO?

All suggestion can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you know the answer yourself, you have done the first important step, that's verifying your website/domain in your Google+ page.

Now just like any other social network, all you have to do is to it keep active, interesting and engaging.

Don't forget to use the Google+ buttons and/or widgets on your website. also it's good to know that now that you've verified your domain, each new follower/fan to your Google plus, is similar to one click of 1+ button on your website, so if you have 100 followers, the button on the verified domain will show +100.

Comment: Ok for +1 button. How can I keep active Google+ page aside from presenting blog posts?

Comment: Well, you should have content other than your blog updates, unlike you blog, fans and Google+ followers will get instant updates, so it's also important to know their online times... that's same for Facebook and Twitter too, but hey, I guess that's everybody's problem, I too have problem with keeping it up all the time. I'm not sure what your website is about, but you can just take a look at what other people in your category are doing, also it may help if you google about it, for example "engaging content social network "...

Comment: Ok right. Indeed, keeping it up all the time is not so easy.

Comment: _How can I keep active Google+ page aside from presenting blog posts?_ - Engage! Circle your followers back, comment on their posts, engage with them! But don't engage for the sake of engaging, that is, if you don't have anything useful or relevant to add to the conversation, don't. Join communities, post there. Also, would be a good idea not to post exclusively about your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You've started off correctly by associating the site.  You now need to simply use Google+ and build up a following.  In this sense, G+ is no different that Facebook...both services only provide social signals for your site if are being sociable.

So start adding people to your circles, participate in relevant discussions and add a link back to your site where appropriate, enable the +1 button on your site for visitors to hit, etc.  All of these actions will slowly build a following.

To speed up the process, a company blog where all posts (excerpt only) are posted to Google+ is an excellent idea assuming the blog receives new content regularly.

Comment: Ok for +1 button and adding people to circles. Do you know other process I can implement on my website aside from a blog to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

You make like to read [this nice lengthy post](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-plus-marketing-guide/) on the Kissmetrics blog. You'll find a lot of "takeaways" that sum up what you can do.

One key point is that you must continually be engaged, responsive and informative. So the most important thing is that you create a strategy and a plan upfront and stick to it. It takes some time to prepare media and images to create good quality content to become the attention you want.

If you combine your posts with links to your blog you can gain more insights about usage patterns than without. Use some analytics to know when (time/day/events) your posts had the most impact.

You'll want to give good copywriting a shot, see lots of good examples on the [copyblogger](http://www.copyblogger.com/blog/) blog. You compete with all the other posts, so knowledge about magnetic headlines and writing is mandatory.